GitHub API call fails with "expected map type under "required_status_checks", got []interface {}"
I am trying to set up branch protection for a new repository on GitHub through the API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-branch-protection). When trying it with gh cli I get the error message "expected map type under "required_status_checks", got []interface {}" My command looks like this
gh api \ --method PUT \ -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \ /repos/OWNER/REPO/branches/BRANCH/protection \ -F "required_status_checks[strict]=true" \ -f "required_status_checks[contexts[]]=build" \ -F "enforce_admins=false" \ -f "dismissal_restrictions[users[]]=null" \ -f "dismissal_restrictions[teams[]]=null" \ -F "required_pull_request_reviews[dismiss_stale_reviews]=true" \ -F "required_pull_request_reviews[require_code_owner_reviews]=false" \ -F "required_pull_request_reviews[required_approving_review_count]=1" \ -F "required_pull_request_reviews[require_last_push_approval]=false" \ -f "bypass_pull_request_allowances[users[]]=null" \ -f "bypass_pull_request_allowances[teams[]]=null" \ -f "restrictions[users[]]=null" \ -f "restrictions[teams[]]=team1" \ -f "restrictions[apps[]]=null" \ -F "require_linear_history=false" \ -F "allow_force_pushes=true" \ -F "allow_deletions=false" \ -F "block_creations=false" \ -F "required_conversation_solution=false" \ -F "lock_branch=false" \ -F "allow_fork_syncing=false"
with OWNER, REPO and BRANCH replaced accordingly.
I suspect required_status_checks[contexts[]]=build is the problem so I tried putting build in quotation marks and braces but to no avail. I also tried using curl and although this way it technically works, I need a token for my use-case and no token configuration worked with curl so far. So I went for gh cli instead.
